# PHP - Cannot connect to mysql on aws ec2

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to connect to the mysql server from the terminal on my local system but cannot connect to it from my php code.

```
<!-- Establish conenction to sql -->
<?php

session_start();

$servername = "ec2-xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database_name";

// Create connection, the code hangs on this line
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

?>
```

The code seems to hang on the 'new sqli' line. I tried placing it inside a try-catch block, but the catch block is never executed. Nothing gets executed beyond that line.

Edit: Dipti suggest that I place ini_set('display_errors', 1); on top on the php file. This gave me an output saying that mysqli couldn't be found. Doing a "sudo apt install php-mysql" fixed the issue.

Comment: Please check error in error log into apache server. Also try to print receiving error while connect

if (!$con)
  {
  die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

Comment: Your connect sql file must be in that amazon server , and servername should be `localhost` not amazon link

Comment: @Dipti /var/log/apache2/error.log is empty. The code doesn't get executed beyond the 'new sqli' line, so trying to print the receiving error doesn't do anything.

Comment: @DavidJP I've connected to mysql servers remotely before using php, so I believe that this should work too.

Comment: @Cracin: try to display ini_set('display_errors', 1); write into top of screen in page. Remove db and just try to connect with server. Are you able to get your access page log in access log file?

Comment: You should check the permission of MySQL before access remotely. By default MySQL will not accept any remote requests.

Comment: @Dipti ini_set('display_errors', 1); did it! I got an output saying that mysqli couldn't be found. I proceeded to do a "sudo apt install php-mysql" and that fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cracin: Enjoy. Please accept my comment or make useful. After install you can verify into phpinfo. It should display installed extension

Answer (score 0):

You connect with `sql` server and your `server name` should be `localhost` not amazon link.